# PostgreSQL "json_to_recordset" equivalent in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-5.6

Had to switch backends (thanks AWS!), just wondering if there exists an equivalent in mysql (5.6.10) for a function like this in PostgreSQL.

```
let query = `INSERT INTO "schema".table(a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h)
SELECT  * FROM  jsonb_to_recordset('` + JSON.stringify(event) +`') as t("a" varchar(10), "b" varchar(10), "c" int, "d" json, "e" json, "f" json, "g" json, "h" json)`
```

Yes I know json isn't a field type in 5.6.10 (thanks AWS!) I'm prepared to make them text fields and stringify the object. But if I can do it in a one-liner, rather than looping through the array to build a string, that'd be great.

Comment: it is only a string anyways make a CONCAT

Comment: MySQL 8.0 has `json_table()`. But in 5.6, where there is no JSON support at all, this will be challenging to achieve.